# Не изменяются типы функций по умолчанию

Tags: typescript

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с казалось бы частой проблемой, но по какой-то причине не смог найти решения.
Необходимо заменить тип для стандартного метода `Object.keys`, чтобы тип возвращаемого значения был `keyof` от типа переданного значения, иначе мапинг после сыпет ошибку вида `string` не является индексатором для `T`.

Описал типы в отдельном файле `custom.d.ts`:

```typescript
declare global {
    interface ArrayConstructor {
        isArray(arg: ReadonlyArray<any> | Readonly<any>): arg is ReadonlyArray<any>
    }

    interface ObjectConstructor {
        static keys<T extends object>(arg: T): (keyof T)[]
    }
}
```

Подключил его в `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    ...,
    "include": [ ..., "custom.d.ts" ]
}
```

Однако это не работает. Работает только если написать те же типы непосредственно в файле с кодом, который использует эти методы.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.